# Microsoft Access Form Auto Shifting Over when Typing in Text Box

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access, if a user does not have the screen of the form maxed out like the first image.

[image]

Then when I go to type in the Comment section, the form shifts to the right and I can’t see the information to the left of it.

[image]

My question would be how do I stop the form from shifting over. I have users that use this form on multiple screen sizes.

Answer (score 2):

1. Turn off form scroll bars in the form properties.
2. Make the form not so horrendously humongous.  (You **don't** need text boxes that wide.)
3. Use a sub-form instead.
4. Make the form "prettier" and more user-friendly.  It looks like you slapped it together with a wizard and didn't change anything afterwards. Find some tutorials about form building, creating a positive user-friendly experience, etc.

Comment: You had me at "horrendously humongous" ;-)

Comment: While I certainly agree with point 2 of your answer, I disagree with point 1. If people with different screen sizes are going to use a form, you shouldn't disable scroll bars, since it might break the form to the point of it being unusable on small screens. Ideally, they shouldn't be visible, but Access won't show them when they're not needed. Also, I don't know what you want exactly with a subform.